# VSCode - find and replace with regexp, but keep word in the middle

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have multiple occurrences of

```dart
AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('WORDING_STR')
```

in my code, that I would like to change to

```dart
LocaleKeys.WORDING_STR.tr()
```

Is it possible to do it with regular expressions, so I can keep whatever is in the code as WORDING_STR?

example:

Replace `AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('finish_status')` to `LocaleKeys.finish_status.tr()`

Comment: There was no flutter-related content in this question, so I removed the flutter tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In VSCode, try this regex to find the occurrences:

```
AppLocalizations\.of\(context\)\.translate\('(\w+)'\)
```

And this one to replace:

```
LocaleKeys.$1.tr()
```

**Explanation**

`\w` means `match a word character only`. And because it's wrapped around parens it creates a `capturing group` that we can back-reference with `$1` to use the captured word in the first group to replace the text. Check it out on https://regex101.com/ to get a detailed explanation of all kinds of regexes.

**Screenshots**

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Screenshot before] | [image: Screenshot after] |

Comment: May i know what '(\w+)' means in this code, also why you use $1 in replace? Thank you for the help

Comment: `\w` means match a word character only. And because it's wrapped around parens it creates a `capturing group` that we can back-reference with `$1` in the replace and use the captured word to replace the text. Check it out on https://regex101.com/ to get the explanations.

Comment: this is exactly what I am looking for! something so small but so useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @lepsch for solution to my question.

added, In my case I found that i had prettier in my vscode that format my code like this

```
AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                    .translate('WORDING_STR')
```

[image: Prettier add whitespace in my code]

The solution is add whitespace `[\s\n]` in regex so the result will still match the case

```
AppLocalizations\.of\(context\)+[\s\n]+\.translate\('(\w+)'\)
```

The Result:
[image: The Result]

But unfortunately this will make mess if i had code like this:
[image]